# Hepatitis B symptoms in less than a week?

Tags: hepatitis

I've read that hepatitis B symptoms in otherwise healthy adults typically present themselves between 6 weeks and 6 months, with one site indicating as early as 2 weeks.

How rare would presentation of symptoms be in 3-5 days?